# Do I have to write separate UI code for every different os?

Tags: android, user-interface, mobile, xamarin, cross-platform

i am new to xamarin.

1) I wonder if it's possible in xamarin to write single ui code that can be used in all platforms - android, ios, windows. Or do i have to write separete ui code for every platform  ?

2) If it's possible to use single ui code for all platforms, would it be good practice to do so ?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of Xamarin that you *don't* have to write platform-specific code?

Comment: Review what `Xamarin Forms` can do for you : https://www.xamarin.com/forms

Answer (score 0):

No.  [Xamarin Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms) provides a single UI API that you can write your mobiles apps in, that will be translated to the native UI surface for each platform.

You can also use Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android to write apps using the native platform SDK - this means you will have to write a separate UI layer for each platform, but can still share domain, services, data, etc code between platforms.